# Is there a way to do a select with two lists being matched in WHERE clause?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I need to do a select but I need to match two lists in the WHERE clause to filter my results. Something like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TAB1
WHERE FieldPartition = W
AND Field1 IN (X1,X2...X600)
AND Field2 IN (Y1,Y1...Y600);
```

But with the select returning only if X1 matches Y1, X2 Y2, etc.

I did the WHERE clause with a bunch of OR between AND in parenthesis, and that worked, but I need other way.

```sql
SELECT * FROM TAB1
WHERE FieldPartition = W
AND (Field1 = X1 AND Field2 = Y2) OR
    (Field1 = X2 AND Field2 = Y2) OR
    (Field1 = X600 AND Field2 = Y600);
```

The code above works as expected, but it takes a long long time to run because the table is huge and I would love something faster.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Tagging this as "SQL" is misleading since Hive is a no-sql database.

Comment: You're right, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, it's not possible in Hive with a single straightforward query, since you can only have one column in `IN` clause, while you need to match two columns from the table with the pairs of values. See similar discussion [here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/multiple-columns-in-where-clause-not-working-in-HIVE/td-p/48373).

The simplest (yet likely the least efficient) thing you can do to achieve your goal is to match an aggregate on aggregate, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM TAB1
WHERE FieldPartition = W
AND CONCAT(Field1,',',Field2) IN ('X1,Y1','X2,Y2'...'X600,Y600');
```

This will, however, run `CONCAT` on each row of `TAB1`, and this is likely not what you'd want.

If you want something more structured, you may want to create a table, e.g. `FILTER_TAB`, with columns `X` and `Y`, load all your filter values there and then select using a `JOIN`, e.g.

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM FILTER_TAB f
JOIN TAB1 t1
ON (f.X=t1.Field1 AND f.Y=t1.Field2)
WHERE t1.FieldPartition = W;
```

You may want to do `LEFT JOIN` or `LEFT OUTER JOIN` depending on your requirements then.

Comment: Yeah, that second solution will work... Thanks a lot, saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
   SELECT * FROM TAB1
     WHERE FieldPartition = W
     AND Field1 IN (X1,X2...X600)
     AND Field1 = Field2;
```

Just edited since I realized that the check for `Field2 IN (...)` was redundant.

Comment: That doesn't work because X1 can have rows with multiple Y, but I need the specific row that X1 matches Y1 (but have different values).

Comment: Please provide some examples of your data. I don't understand what you mean by "X1 matches Y1 (but have different values)". That seems contradictory.

Comment: Think about a bank agency identified by a number, this agency has many accounts identified by a bigger number...

X are the agencies and Y are the accounts, i need results where X1 agency matches Y1 account, X2 agency matches Y2 account, etc.

Where X and Y are a specific list of agencies and accounts.

The problem is X1, for example, can have many Y's.

Comment: Sounds like you need normalize your data into multiple tables.